# Reference Request for Synthesis

Tags: reference-request, formal-methods

New to the world of software verification and synthesis. It was suggested to me that the book "Principles of Model Checking" is a good reference for verification, but I am clueless about synthesis. Could someone refer a good book?

Comment: Try these [slides](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~frankel/HonoraryDay09/Slides/AmirPnueli.pdf)

Comment: What do you want to synthesize? Hardware? FSMs? Software? Could you be more precise?

Comment: Thanks for the slides. FSM and Software, but specially FSM.

Comment: Another set of slide: From Verification to Synthesis

Comment: Many thanks for the new set of slides ........

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the link. Here it [is](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/papers/fmco06.ps.gz). I did notice that googling "From Verification to Synthesis" turns up a lot of nice stuff. Anyway, the slides were from Moshe Vardi. The work of Orna Kupferman seems highly relevant too.

Comment: Thanks again for the information provided. I noticed you had asked a great question (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/386/path-to-formal-methods) earlier. Did you find the best way? I could not comment on that question that is why I am leaving a comment here.

Comment: I don't know what the best path to formal methods is. Certainly having a strong undergraduate degree in mathematics really helps.

Comment: @DaveClarke, would you like to post your links as an answer so we can [clean this question up](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/560/is-it-all-right-to-cleanup-comment-answered-questions?cb=1)?

Comment: Done. I posted a sort of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these slides http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~frankel/HonoraryDay09/Slides/AmirPnueli.pdf or these ones http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/papers/fmco06.ps.gz.

Also try googling "From Verification to Synthesis" and look at the work of Moshe Vardi and Orna Kupferman.